# Trying to get rid of annoying little blue links below my images

Tags: html, css

[Photos of the icons with the blue line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACvSg.png)

I'm trying to get rid of these on my site (the blue lines below the icons) (I'm coding in HTML and CSS) I've tried a bunch of different things like text-decoration: none;
borders:none;(for images)
Can't seem to find how to solve this

This is what my HTML looks like:

```css
.socialmediawidgets{
     text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="socialmediawidgets">
    <a href="[full link to your Twitter]">
    <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter"  src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/01_twitter.png" width="35" height="35" />
    </a>
    <a href="[full link to your Pinterest]">
    <img title="Pinterest" alt="Pinterest" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/13_pinterest.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     <a href="[full link to your Facebook page]">
     <img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/02_facebook.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     <a href="[full link to your LinkedIn]">
     <img title="LinkedIn" alt="LinkedIn" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/07_linkedin.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     <a href="[full link to your Instagram]">
     <img title="Instagram" alt="RSS" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/10_instagram.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try it all that, but not for `a`, for example : `.socialmediawidgets a {text-decoration:none;}` and so on. That "blue line" isn't part of image but `a` (link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `text-decoration:none`on the CSS. Check [the Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp)

Note I´ve created a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) ".socialmediawidgets a"

This way, **the links affected, are only the ones under `.socialmediawidgets` div**

```css
.socialmediawidgets{
     text-align: left;
}

   .socialmediawidgets a {
    text-decoration:none;
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="socialmediawidgets">
    <a href="[full link to your Twitter]">
    <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter"  src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/01_twitter.png" width="35" height="35" />
    </a>
    <a href="[full link to your Pinterest]">
    <img title="Pinterest" alt="Pinterest" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/13_pinterest.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     <a href="[full link to your Facebook page]">
     <img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/02_facebook.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     <a href="[full link to your LinkedIn]">
     <img title="LinkedIn" alt="LinkedIn" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/07_linkedin.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     <a href="[full link to your Instagram]">
     <img title="Instagram" alt="RSS" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/10_instagram.png" width="35" height="35" />
     </a>
     </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Isolating the scope to your code, you can add text-decoration: none to .a.
If you are expanding the code and would like to isolate the removing of underscore to the area you have now you should use:

```
.socialmediawidgets a {
text-deoration: none;
 }
```

See attached snippet that shows your code and the change in CSS:

```css
.socialmediawidgets{
   text-align: left;
 }
 
 a {
 text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="socialmediawidgets">
 <a href="[full link to your Twitter]">
 <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/01_twitter.png" width="35" height="35" />
 </a>
 
 <a href="[full link to your Pinterest]">
 <img title="Pinterest" alt="Pinterest" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/13_pinterest.png" width="35" height="35" />
 </a>
 
 <a href="[full link to your Facebook page]">
 <img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/02_facebook.png" width="35" height="35" />
 </a>
 
 <a href="[full link to your LinkedIn]">
 <img title="LinkedIn" alt="LinkedIn" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/07_linkedin.png" width="35" height="35" />
 </a>
 
 <a href="[full link to your Instagram]">
 <img title="Instagram" alt="RSS" src="https://socialmediawidgets.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/10_instagram.png" 

width="35" height="35" />
 </a>
 
</div>
</div>
```